# Hotwire turbo streams returning head :no_content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo

I have a system with posts and comments, each `Post` `has_many` `Comment`s. I am trying to setup a turbostream so that when you post a comment it displays immediately.

Everything works in that data is persisted to the database but it seems like the turbo stream is not properly returning.  When I hit the "comment" button nothing changes and I get a `:no_content` message for `CommentsController#create`

```
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:11:in `create'
[ActiveJob] Enqueued Turbo::Streams::ActionBroadcastJob (Job ID: b0be3a08-d7bb-4216-aac5-2f274a22dcbf) to Async(default) with arguments: "Z2lkOi8vY2lhby9Qb3N0LzM", {:action=>:append, :target=>"comments", :locals=>{:comment=>#<GlobalID:0x00007fa94123baf8 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://ciao/Comment/16>>}, :partial=>"comments/comment"}
[ActiveJob] Enqueued Turbo::Streams::ActionBroadcastJob (Job ID: 382e45b4-7a8f-4c8c-9e48-819fab0c19c4) to Async(default) with arguments: "Z2lkOi8vY2lhby9Qb3N0LzM", {:action=>:replace, :target=>#<GlobalID:0x00007fa9401ea938 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://ciao/Comment/16>>, :locals=>{:comment=>#<GlobalID:0x00007fa9401ea0f0 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://ciao/Comment/16>>}, :partial=>"comments/comment"}
No template found for CommentsController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 37ms (ActiveRecord: 8.5ms | Allocations: 8931)
```

Turbo seems to work as far as creating the comment in the database, and sending back a comments POST request which I can see in the browser network tab.  I'm wondering why there is `:no_content` and why the comments are not displaying until a page refresh.

`Place.rb`

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :place
  has_many :comments
  broadcasts
end
```

`Comment.rb`

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  broadcasts_to :post
end
```

`comment_controller.rb`

```
def new
    @comment = @post.comments.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = current_user.comments.create!(comment_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
         format.turbo_stream do
             render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.append(@comment, partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: @comment })
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @comment.post.place }
      end
    end
  end
```

On the post I render the comment as a partial:

```
 <div class="post__comments--inner">
   <%= render '/comments/show', post: post %>
 </div>
```

Then `comments/_show.html.erb`

```
  <%= turbo_stream_from post %>
  <%= render post.comments %>
  <% puts post.comments %>
  <div class="comments__post">
    <%= turbo_frame_tag "new_comment", src:  new_post_comment_path(post), target: "_top" %>
  </div>
```

`_comment.html.erb`

```
<div class="comment" id="<%= dom_id comment %>">
  <%= comment.content %>
</div>
```

`new.html.erb`

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "new_comment", target: "_top" do %>
  <%= form_with model: [@comment.post, @comment], class: "comment-row__form",
     data: { controller: "reset_form", action: "turbo:submit-end->reset_form#reset" }  do |form| %>
      <%= form.text_area :content, class: "comment-form--input form-control", data: {target: "comments.body"} %>
      <%= form.hidden_field :post_id, value: @comment.post.id %>
      <%= form.submit "comment", class: "btn btn-primary mt-2 mt-sm-0 ml-sm-3" %>
 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I think I may have found the issue but I'm not sure why it's happening the final think in the log is:

```
Turbo::StreamsChannel transmitting "<turbo-stream action=\"replace\" target=\"comment_36\"><template>  <div class=\"comment\" id=\"comment_36\">\n    <div class=\"comment__user\">\n
```

to my thinking it would be `action=\"append\"` rather than replace, especially since `comment_36` does not currently exist on the page yet.

Comment: You are not rendering anythning in the block , e.g  format.turbo_stream { render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.append(@comment) }

Comment: I was just copying from the hotwire demo where they have: 

`respond_to do |format|`
  
  `format.turbo_stream`
   
  `format.html { redirect_to @room }`

`end`
I have added a render block and it is returning successfully but nothing is being appended.
I have updated my question to reflect the changes.

Comment: it indeed needs to be append since its a new comment

Comment: That's why I'm confused about why the turbo streams channel is saying the action is replace.

Comment: I may have given a bad snippet above, try my answer perhaps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following this example from the docs:

```
 respond_to do |format|
  format.turbo_stream do
    render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.append(:comments, partial: "comments/comment",
      locals: { comment: @comment })
  end
 end
```

This should append it to a div in your html with an id of comments.

Comment: Thanks your original comment was an important step in the right direction, I think the reason nothing is still rendering has to do with the specify of the `target="comments"` since each post on the page has a comments field I don't think Turbo knows where to append.

Comment: Indeed it is looking for an element with a dom id comments to append to.

Comment: If it helps anyone else, don't forget to include `render turbo_stream:`